# Trying to pull zipcodes from one dataframe into a another dataframe of addresses

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of addresses with no zipcodes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'address1':['1 o\'toole st','2 main st','3 high street','5 foo street','10 foo street'],
                   'address2':['town1',np.nan,np.nan,'Bartown',np.nan],
                   'address3':[np.nan,'village','city','county2','county3']})
df1['zipcode']=''
df1

        address1 address2 address3 zipcode
0   1 o'toole st    town1      NaN        
1      2 main st      NaN  village        
2  3 high street      NaN     city        
3   5 foo street  Bartown  county2        
4  10 foo street      NaN  county3
```

And I have a second dataframe with addresses and zipcodes. Note, this is in the same order as `df1`, but it's not like this in the real data I'm working with:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'address1':['1 o\'toole st','2 main st','7 mill street','5 foo street','10 foo street'],
                   'address2':['town1','village','city','Bartown','county3'],
                   'address3':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'county2','USA'],
                   'zipcode': ['er45','qw23','rt67','yu89','yu83']})
df2

        address1 address2 address3 zipcode
0   1 o'toole st    town1      NaN    er45
1      2 main st  village      NaN    qw23
2  7 mill street     city      NaN    rt67
3   5 foo street  Bartown  county2    yu89
4  10 foo street  county3      USA    yu83
```

I want to check if the addresses in `df1` are in `df2`, and if so, drag the zipcodes into `df1`.

This is where I'm having a bit of trouble, not sure if it's the best way to approach it.

What I've done so far is create a primary key for both dataframes, using the first two lines off the address: `address 1` and `address 2`, stripping all white spaces and nonalpha, converting to lower:

```
df1['key'] = (df1['address1'] + df1['address2']).str.lower().str.replace(' ', '').str.replace('\W', '')


df2['key'] = (df2['address1'] + df2['address2']).str.lower().str.replace(' ', '').str.replace('\W', '')


print(df1)

        address1 address2 address3 zipcode                key
0   1 o'toole st    town1      NaN             1otoolesttown1
1      2 main st      NaN  village                        NaN
2  3 high street      NaN     city                        NaN
3   5 foo street  Bartown  county2          5foostreetbartown
4  10 foo street      NaN  county3                        NaN

print(df2)

        address1 address2 address3 zipcode                 key
0   1 o'toole st    town1      NaN    er45      1otoolesttown1
1      2 main st  village      NaN    qw23      2mainstvillage
2  7 mill street     city      NaN    rt67     7millstreetcity
3   5 foo street  Bartown  county2    yu89   5foostreetbartown
4  10 foo street  county3      USA    yu83  10foostreetcounty3
```

Now I'm going to use `np.where` to drag the info over to the empty `zipcode` column in df1, returning `no_match` if a matching address wasn't found:

```
df1['zipcode'] = np.where(df1['key'].isin(df2['key']), df2['zipcode'], 'no_match')

print(df1)

        address1 address2 address3   zipcode                key
0   1 o'toole st    town1      NaN      er45     1otoolesttown1
1      2 main st      NaN  village  no_match                NaN
2  3 high street      NaN     city  no_match                NaN
3   5 foo street  Bartown  county2      yu89  5foostreetbartown
4  10 foo street      NaN  county3  no_match                NaN
```

My problem is with the `key` created for df1. As you can see, some of them are `NaN`. This is due to the address formatting which is different to `df2`. That's just how the datasets are that I'm currently working with.

I tried to get around this problem by skipping any `NaN` and adding the next row, but get a ValueError:

```
# add address1 + address2 if it's not null, otherwise use address3

df1['key'] = (df1['address1'] + (df1['address2'] if pd.notnull(df1['address2']) else df1['address3']))

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any feedback or advice on how to tackle this is much appreciated. If there's an easier way to do this I'd love to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace missing values by `df1['address3']`:

```
df1['key'] = df1['address1'] + df1['address2'].fillna(df1['address3'])
```

instead:

```
df1['key'] = (df1['address1'] + (df1['address2'] if 
                                   pd.notnull(df1['address2']) else df1['address3']))
```

More information about you error is in [using if truth statements with-pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#using-if-truth-statements-with-pandas).

Comment: Do you ever sleep? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I would first replace the NaN values with empty strings, and concatenate the 3 address columns to get the address in one column, a bit like you did:

```
# filling NaN values
df1.fillna('', inplace=True)
df2.fillna('', inplace=True)

# concatenate the address columns
df1['address'] = df1['address1']+df1['address2']+df1['address3']
df2['address'] = df2['address1']+df2['address2']+df2['address3']
```

Then set the new 'address' column as the index in both DataFrames:

```
df1.set_index('address', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('address', inplace=True)
```

And finally add the zip code to df1:

```
df1['zipcode'] = df2['zipcode']
```

Here is the result:

```
                            address1       address2        address         zipcode
address                 
1 o'toole sttown1           1 o'toole st    town1                           er45
2 main stvillage            2 main st                       village         qw23
3 high streetcity           3 high street                   city            NaN
5 foo streetBartowncounty2  5 foo street    Bartown         county2         yu89
10 foo streetcounty3        10 foo street                   county3         yu89
```

Comment: The problem is, I only want the first two address entries. You are adding `df1['address1']+df1['address2']+df1['address3']` which is fine for records with a `NaN` but for records with complete addresses, I end up with more rows combined than I originally wanted.

Comment: I have updated my question and added 'USA' to a record in `df2` which will show how your method won't 100% work. There will be a nan in your final results with my new `df2` if you re-run your code.

Comment: By the way thank you for taking the time to read my massive question.

Comment: OK I see your problem. I think jezrael's anwser is better than mine and should work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

```
df1['key'] = (df1['address1'] + (df1['address2'] if pd.notnull(df1['address2']) else df1['address3']))
```

The `if` used here leads to the error, because `pd.notnull` generates a boolean series but the `if` operator requires one boolean value.
You can solve it by using [pandas.Series.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df1['key'] = (df1['address1'] +
             df1['address2'].where(pd.notnull(df1['address2']), df1['address3'])) \
             .str.lower().str.replace(' ', '').str.replace('\W', '')
```

This will generate a `df1` with the keys you are looking for:

```
        address1 address2 address3                 key
0   1 o'toole st    town1      NaN      1otoolesttown1
1      2 main st      NaN  village      2mainstvillage
2  3 high street      NaN     city     3highstreetcity
3   5 foo street  Bartown  county2   5foostreetbartown
4  10 foo street      NaN  county3  10foostreetcounty3
```

And now you can merge the zipcodes.

Comment: What does the second part of `where` do? The `y` here:  `.where(condition,y)`

Comment: Is sort of `else`. From the docs: _Where condition is True, keep the original value. Where False, replace with corresponding value from other._  other is your `y`